# How do i extract arguments using yargs?

Tags: node.js, yargs

I'm using `yargs` lib in project. Importing it like this:

```
import { argv } from 'yargs';
```

Accessing all of args as following:

```
console.log('!!! start work', argv);
```

which gives the output smth like this:

```
!!! start work {
  _: [
    ...list of args provided in command line...
  ]
  '$0': 'tools/update-imports/src'
}
```

I need to access all the stuff in '_' array, but `argv._` fails complaining there's no such property.

Cannot find on docs this as well.

Still i think there should be a way to do it. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it can be accessed with bracket notation:

```
argv['_']
```